# VBA Excel Date Reformatting

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a vba code to pull two excel workbooks into one workbook. Workbook 1 is from the previous business day and workbook 2 is the 2nd most previous business day. For example, on Monday, I will pull workbook data from Friday and Thursday into a separate workbook. The workbooks are named as "results 07.26.2019" so the date format is mm.dd.yyyy. When I try formatting my date by mm.dd.yyyy. it will either ignore my format or will produce errors. I have tried defining my date like:

```
Dim dDate As Date
dDate = Date
dDate = Format(dDate, "mm.dd.yyyy")
```

The default format is "mm/dd/yyyy", is there trick/code that will allow me to custom format my date?

Thanks

Comment: `Format` returns a `Variant/String` so you shouldn't assign its result to `dDate`. What's the rest of your code, where you attempt to use the formatted date?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, just want to clarify, so I shouldn't use the format function?

Comment: See the posted answer. If you want, you could get rid of `dDate` entirely and just use `Date` within `Format`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Format` returns a string, so trying to catch that formatted date string back into a variable that is typed as a date isn't going to work, or if it does you will just end up with what you started with.

Declare a new variable like

```
Dim sDate as String
```

and then set the return of `Format` to that string version of your date variable

```
sDate = Format(dDate, "mm.dd.yyyy")
```